# Sharing as little as possible with outside designer with WPF/Blend

Tags: wpf, xaml, expression-blend

We've started work on a WPF application a client. They have an in-house designer that they would like to use for doing the visual design of the application. This I have no problem with. We just did something similar with a webapp we created with them, and it worked well.

We've pointed their designer at Blend, and he's going to go off and learn while we're doing development on the application.

We already have a shared Dropbox folder that these resources will probably live in, as our in-house source control is (understandably) locked down, and I doubt I'd be able to introduce something like a shared Mercurial repo.

What I would like to do is share the bare minimum with the designer, only the xaml files if I can. As this is my first large WPF project, and my first one involving Blend, and an outside designer, I'm not sure on the best practices for this, and would like to get input before moving down this path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Blend quite a bit and for the most part the interface and an outline of the Model and CodeBehind/ViewModel is all you need.

I typically do all of the work, (Design and Code), but Blend can host design time data which can be created using a model.  If I have a very well designed and documented ViewModel I can pretty well write an interface around it.  If your Model and other logic are going to be in binaries that you send them, be sure the exposed members are well documented so that they know what to expect behavior-wise.

If you can get approval to release more of your code to them, so much the better.  Actual code goes a long way above and beyond documentation.

Comment: There is no actual logic in the WPF project other than the view models themselves, various behaviors/converters, very thin service proxy classes, and the setup for Caliburn Micro. I was hoping to get away with even less, as the designer works for the customer. I suppose I can move the actual view models and proxies off into another assembly, and implement a NameTransformer...

Comment: I don't know how good the designer is, but, ideally they should be able to make do with a built assembly with documented methods and properties.  Really it depends on the sophistication of the application, but really they should be able to work with documentation telling them input output and exception cases.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. The view models and other assorted code files were moved into their own assembly.